# How can I add a field (for each returned record) in the query output containing the total number or the records returned by my query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem working on a MySql query that can return 0,1,>1 records as output.

I have to add a field (to each rows) that contains the total number of rows. So for example if the total number or records returned by my query is 4 the **record_number** field hat to contains this values in all te returned rows.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    LS.id                                                                           AS livestock_id,
    LS.parent_livestock_species_id                                                  AS parent_livestock_species_id,
    LS.livestock_species_name_en                                                    AS livestock_species_name_en,
    IFNULL(LSN.livestock_species_name, LS.livestock_species_name_en)                AS livestock_species_name,  
    LSN.description                                                                 AS description,
    LS.image_link                                                                   AS image_link,
    count(*)                                                                        AS record_number
FROM LivestockSpecies                                                               AS LS
LEFT JOIN LivestockSpeciesName                                                      AS LSN
      ON LSN.livestock_species_id = LS.id AND LSN.language_id = 1
WHERE
    LS.id = 1
OR
    LS.parent_livestock_species_id = 1
```

Doing in tis way I am obtaining this error message:

```
#42000In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'digital_services_DB.LS.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the languages table doesn't change the number of rows (this is reasonable because of the `left join`), so you can just add a subquery, in either the `from` or `select`:

```
select . . .
       (select count(*) from LivestockSpecies ls2 where ls2.id = 1 or ls2.parent_livestock_species_id = 1
       ) as total_number
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions, so this is more aptly calculated as:

```
select . . .
       count(*) over () as total_number
```